# file_get_contents() via proxy in httpd

Tags: php, apache2, php-5.2

I try to the get source of a page using file_get_contents() via proxy using the following code

```
$aContext = array(
'http' => array(
    'proxy' => 'tcp://proxy.ssn.net:8080',
    'request_fulluri' => true,
),);
$cxContext = stream_context_create($aContext);
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.indiaglitz.com/channels/tamil/reviews.asp', False, $cxContext);
echo $homepage;
```

This works when i execute the php file via terminal, but i don't get the output when i run the file through browser using httpd(Apache 2).

This works in Apache2 installed in Ubuntu, but not in httpd installed in Fedora 17.

Where is the mistake??

Comment: Are you running in the terminal and through the browser on the same server?  php settings can turn off file_get_contents() for non local files.  (By the way, you shouldn't be using file_get_contents to fetch files from urls.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common cause of this is SELinux not permitting httpd to make network connections.

To resolve it, you need to change an SELinux boolean value (which will automatically persist across reboots). You may also want to restart httpd to reset the proxy worker, although this isn't strictly required.

## setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1

Answer (score 0):

So I see that one server works on your ubuntu, but not on the fedora server.  The fedora server probably has the option Allow_url_fopen (file_get_contents uses fopen()) turned off in its php settings.  http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php

BUT!  Don't change that security setting.  If you want to download something, curl works well without opening the security hole.

Comment: allow_url_fopen is turned on for both Local and Master value. I checked using phpinfo().

Comment: And i tried curl, It gives same error, (i.e) it works in terminal but not in browser.